# Route 53 Strip WWW from All URLs

Tags: dns, azure-web-app-service, amazon-route53, url-rewrite-module

I need to remove WWW. from all my URLs on route 53.  I have a web.config rewrite rule on my website that works with my Azure VMs but when converting to webapps it is not allowed.  A mistake in the past informed users that their personal website was www.john.domain.com or www.jane.domain.com.  With the Rewrite rule on it works going to VMs in azure but not to Webapps.  I am looking to remove the extra www. from all url requests.  I am using Route 53 for DNS and I have a Redirect rule for Naked DNS domain.com already to go to www.domain.com but I would like to have another redirect or rewrite that works like the web.config rule.

```
<rule name="Remove www from 4th level" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" statusCode="200" statusReason="Ok"/>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the http/https from your pattern.  Your conditions should look more like:

```
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^http://www\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$"/>     
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^https://www\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$"/>
  </conditions>
```

Comment: I show the web.config but I need to remove the www at a higher layer as part of the DNS redirect at route 53.